# How to fix: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

```
I have this classes as of know:
```

`public class Position {`
`private double x;`
`private double y;`

`public Position(double x, double y) {`
`this.x = x;`
`this.y = y;`
`}`

`public Position() {`
`this(0, 0);`
`}`

`public double getX() {`
`return x;`
`}`

`public double getY() {`
`return y;`
`}`

`public String toString() {`
`return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";`
`}`

`}`

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

`public class Brain {`
`private ArrayList<Neuron> neurons;`

`public Brain() {`
`this.neurons = new ArrayList<Neuron>();`
`}`

`public int getNbNeurons() {`
`return neurons.size();`
`}`

`public Neuron getNeuron(int index) {`
`return neurons.get(index);`
`}`

`public void addNeuron(Position position, double attenuation) {`

`Neuron n = new Neuron(position, attenuation);`
`this.neurons.add(n);`
`}`

`public void addCumulativeNeuron(Position pos, double attenuation) {`

`CumulativeNeuron cn = new CumulativeNeuron(pos, attenuation);`
`this.neurons.add(cn);`
`}`

`public void stimulate(int index, double stimulus) {`

`Neuron neuron = neurons.get(index);`
`neuron.receivesStimulus(stimulus);`
`}`

`public double probe(int index) {`
`Neuron neuron = neurons.get(index);`
`System.out.println("INDEX IS: " + index);`
`System.out.println("SIGNAL: " + neuron.getSignal());`
`return neuron.getSignal();`

`}`
`public void createConnections() {`
`int size = this.getNbNeurons();`
`for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++) {`
`Neuron n1 = this.getNeuron(i);`
`Neuron n2 = this.getNeuron(i + 1);`
`n1.connection(n2);`
`n2.connection(n1);`
`}`
`if (size > 1) {`
`this.getNeuron(0).connection(this.getNeuron(1));`
`}`
`if (size > 2) {`
`this.getNeuron(0).connection(this.getNeuron(2));`
`}`
`}`

`public String toString() {`
`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`
`sb.append("*----------*\n");`
`sb.append("The brain contains ").append(this.getNbNeurons()).append(" neuron(s)\n");`

`for (Neuron neuron : this.neurons) {`
`sb.append(neuron.toString()).append("\n");`
`}`

`sb.append("*----------*\n");`

`return sb.toString();`
`}`
`}`

```
I'm using this test class called NeuronSimulator
```

`public class NeuronSimulator {`

`public static void main(String[] args) {`
`// TEST PART 1`
`System.out.println("Test part 1:");`
`System.out.println("--------------------");`

`Position position1 = new Position(0, 1);`
`Position position2 = new Position(1, 0);`
`Position position3 = new Position(1, 1);`

`Neuron neuron1 = new Neuron(position1, 0.5);`
`Neuron neuron2 = new Neuron(position2, 1.0);`
`Neuron neuron3 = new Neuron(position3, 2.0);`

`neuron1.connection(neuron2);`
`neuron2.connection(neuron3);`
`neuron1.receivesStimulus(10);`

`System.out.println("Signals : ");`
`System.out.println(neuron1.getSignal());`
`System.out.println(neuron2.getSignal());`
`System.out.println(neuron3.getSignal());`

`System.out.println();`
`System.out.println("First connection of neuron 1");`
`System.out.println(neuron1.getConnection(0));`

`// END TEST PART 1`

`// TEST PART 2`
`System.out.println("Test part 2:");`
`System.out.println("--------------------");`

`Position position5 = new Position(0, 0);`
`CumulativeNeuron neuron5 = new CumulativeNeuron(position5, 0.5);`
`neuron5.receivesStimulus(10);`
`neuron5.receivesStimulus(10);`
`System.out.println("Signal of cumulative neuron -> " + neuron5.getSignal());`

`// END TEST PART 2`

`//TEST PART 3`
`System.out.println();`
`System.out.println("Test part 3:");`
`System.out.println("--------------------");`
`Brain brain = new Brain();`

`brain.addNeuron(new Position(0, 0), 0.5);`
`brain.addNeuron(new Position(0, 1), 0.2);`
`brain.addNeuron(new Position(1, 0), 1.0);`

`brain.addCumulativeNeuron(new Position(1, 1), 0.8);`
`brain.createConnections();`
`brain.stimulate(0, 10);`

`System.out.println("Signal of 3rd neuron -> " + brain.probe(3));`
`System.out.println(brain);`
`// END TEST PART 3`

`}`
`}`

When i run the test class I should get as an output the following:

Test part 3:

--------------------

Signal of 3rd neuron -> 4.800000000000001

The brain contains 4 neuron(s)

The neuron in position (0.0, 0.0) with attenuation 0.5 in connection with

- a neuron in position (0.0, 1.0)

- a neuron in position (1.0, 0.0)

The neuron in position (0.0, 1.0) with attenuation 0.2 in connection with

- a neuron in position (1.0, 0.0)

The neuron in position (1.0, 0.0) with attenuation 1.0 in connection with

- a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

The neuron in position (1.0, 1.0) with attenuation 0.8 without connection

*----------*

But instead of that output I get this one

```
Test part 1:
--------------------
Signals : 
5.0
5.0
10.0

First connection of neuron 1
The neuron in position (1.0, 0.0) with attenuation 1.0 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

Test part 2:
--------------------
Signal of cumulative neuron -> 10.0

Test part 3:
--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:108)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
    at lpasch02.hw3.neurons.Neuron.receivesStimulus(Neuron.java:110)
        .....
```

That means that the program gets stuck in an infinite loop when this method is called

```
public void receivesStimulus(double stimulus) {
        this.signal = stimulus * this.attenuation;
        for (Neuron connection : this.connections) {
            
            connection.receivesStimulus(this.signal);
        }
    }
```

And more especially it seems that this line is the problem

`connection.receivesStimulus(this.signal);`

when I commend out either this line

`brain.createConnections();`

or this line

`brain.stimulate(0, 10);`

the exception disappears and this is the output:

```
Test part 1:
--------------------
Signals : 
5.0
5.0
10.0

First connection of neuron 1
The neuron in position (1.0, 0.0) with attenuation 1.0 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

Test part 2:
--------------------
Signal of cumulative neuron -> 10.0

Test part 3:
--------------------
Before Brain new
Before first addNeuron
Before second addNeuron
Before third addNeuron
Before addCumulativeNeuron
Before createConnections
Before stimultate
After stimultate
INDEX IS: 3
SIGNAL: 0.0
Signal of 3rd neuron -> 0.0
*----------*
The brain contains 4 neuron(s)
The neuron in position (0.0, 0.0) with attenuation 0.5 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 1.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 0.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

The neuron in position (0.0, 1.0) with attenuation 0.2 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 0.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 0.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

The neuron in position (1.0, 0.0) with attenuation 1.0 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 0.0)
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 1.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 1.0)

The neuron in position (1.0, 1.0) with attenuation 0.8 in connection with
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 0.0)
  - a neuron in position (0.0, 1.0)
  - a neuron in position (1.0, 0.0)

*----------*
```

Which again has a mistake because the signal of the 3rd neuron should be 4.800000000000001 and not 0.0

```
Signal of 3rd neuron -> 0.0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this this problem without commenting anything out, putting extra methods, extra characteristics or changing anything on the NeuronSimulator class (this is a project that needs to be this way)

Comment: Every time you call this method you are looping through the same set of `connections` `for (Neuron connection : this.connections)`

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: It's  infinite recursion, similar to an infinite loop. The `receivesStimulus (double)` method gets the first element from `connections`, which passes the `signal` value of that first element to the `receivesStimulus (double)` method, which gets the first element from `connections, which passes the `signal` value of that first element to the `receivesStimulus (double)` method, which gets the first element from `connections`, which ....  So, your program enters infinite recursion everytime `connections` is not empty.

Comment: @tgdavies sorry it's my first time using this site to post a question and I don't know how to fix the format

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer So how can i fix this infinite recursion?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes i know but that was what the assignment said to do:  create a method void receivesStimulus(double stimulus) allowing the
simulation of a neuron. This simulation results in:
storing its value in the neuron's internal signal
of stimulus  multiplied by the attenuation coefficient,
propagating the internal signal to the connected neurons with its call
receivesStimulus method on all elements of the connections list. This call to the receivesStimulus method will be made with a parameter to
internal signal, signal, of the examined neuron (calculated in
previous bullet)

Comment: @carlosS I don't know what `receiveStimulus (double)` is supposed to do. As it stands now, it is infinite recursion because nothing is changed. To solve it, the method has to make a change that causes it to be closer to coming to an end. But, I have no idea what that should be. Stack Overflow isn't suitable for teaching recursion or other programming subjects.

Comment: @carlosS In your last comment, where does it say that it should be recursive?

Comment: @ScaryWombat  "its call receivesStimulus method on all elements of the connections list. This call to the receivesStimulus method will be made with a parameter to internal signal" Doesnt that mean it should be recursive?

Comment: That is not my understanding.  Usually if recursion is used, then loops will not be used.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).